# I cannot transfer ownership in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

My bosses recently have decided to part their ways, so we removed the first boss from the Facebook, yet it shows, that he is the owner of it, as in it is owned by his business. And since he is not so handy with the IT, I took over his account in order to transfer the ownership. 
But when trying to transfer the ownership, Facebook only allows to deny the request, as soon as I press accept, it shows error and says to try it again later. How is that and how can I fix it?

[image]

This is the detailed sequence of what I'm doing:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

...followed by the error in the top image.

Answer (score 0):

Let the new person register a fake business (can be a brand so no details have to be provided) under https://business.facebook.com/ and try to transfer ownership again. Remove the old account from the admins.

Once that's done it will stop showing the error message. I've had a similar but not the same issue, it showed the same error message. Making the receiver account access business manager helped